# pandas matrix calculation till the diagonal

Tags: python, pandas

i'm doing a matrix calculation using pandas in python.

my raw data is in the form of list of strings(which is unique for each row).

```
id     list_of_value
0      ['a','b','c']
1      ['d','b','c']
2      ['a','b','c']
3      ['a','b','c']
```

i have to do a calculate a score with one row and against all the other rows

score calculation algorithm:

```
Step 1: Take value of id 0: ['a','b','c'],
Step 2: find the intersection between id 0 and id 1 , 
        resultant = ['b','c']
Step 3: Score Calculation => resultant.size / id(0).size
```

repeat step 2,3 between id 0 and id 1,2,3, similarly for all the ids.

Create N * N matrix:

```
-  0    1    2  3
0  1    0.6  1  1
1  0.6  1    1  1 
2  1    1    1  1
3  1    1    1  1
```

At present i'm using the pandas dummies approach to calculate the score:

```
s = pd.get_dummies(df.list_of_value.explode()).sum(level=0)
s.dot(s.T).div(s.sum(1))
```

but there is an repetition in calculation after the diagonal of the matrix, the score calculation till diagonal is sufficient. for eg:

calculation of score of ID 0, will be only till ID(row,column) (0,0), score for ID(row,column) (0,1),(0,2),(0,3) can be copied from ID(row,column) (1,0),(2,0),(3,0).

Detail on the calculation:
[image: matrix sample]
i need to calculate till the diagonal, that is **till** the yellow colored box(the diagonal of matrix), the white values are already calculated in the green shaded area (for ref), i just have to transpose the green shaded area to white.

how can i do this in pandas?

Comment: Is the NxN matrix you have above the expected result? What do you mean by 'the score calculation till diagonal is sufficient'? Can you explain the logic

Comment: @davidbilla added more explanation, and yes the NxN matrix is the expected result.

Comment: Are the possible values of the lists known or cheap to calculate?

Comment: just use a double for loop and not perform the calculation if i = j or if i > j (or if i < j) to take advantage of symmetry and the fact that the diagonals are all 1

Comment: @JohnE yeah, you are correct. your assumption is correct and i have updated the question

Comment: This is a strange question in the sense that the dimensions of the answer are huge (NxN) to state the obvious.  Hence, speed would not really appear to be an issue here relative to the dimensionality issue.  But if speed is not an issue here, then I think your approach is actually fine, so I don't really know what the question is.  Sure you can speed this up, but is that actually a problem here?  It might make sense to give some idea as to the actual nature of your real dataset to know what is a good solution.

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar can you have twice the same element in a list of 1 row, like `['a','a','b']` for example?

Comment: @Ben.T no it will be a unique list

Comment: To get a better idea of the data: every list has the same amount of elements, right? Each element is a string of only one character and they are one of the lower case letters. Is that correct so far? You already said you have at least 20k rows, but how big is the size of the lists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all here is a profiling of your code. First all commands separately, and then as you posted it.

```py
%timeit df.list_of_value.explode()
%timeit pd.get_dummies(s)
%timeit s.sum(level=0)
%timeit s.dot(s.T)
%timeit s.sum(1)
%timeit s2.div(s3)
```

The above profiling returned the following results:

```
Explode   : 1000 loops, best of 3: 201 µs per loop
Dummies   : 1000 loops, best of 3: 697 µs per loop
Sum       : 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop
Dot       : 1000 loops, best of 3: 453 µs per loop
Sum2      : 10000 loops, best of 3: 162 µs per loop
Divide    : 100 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop
```

Running Your two lines together results in:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 5.35 ms per loop
```

Using a different approach relying less on the (sometimes expensive) functionality of pandas, the code I created takes just about a third of the time by skipping the calculation for the upper triangular matrix and the diagonal as well.

```py
import numpy as np

# create a matrix filled with ones (thus the diagonal is already filled with ones)
df2 = np.ones(shape = (len(df), len(df)))
for i in range(len(df)):
    d0 = set(df.iloc[i].list_of_value)
    d0_len = len(d0)
    # the inner loop starts at i+1 because we don't need to calculate the diagonal
    for j in range(i + 1, len(df)):
        df2[j, i] = len(d0.intersection(df.iloc[j].list_of_value)) / d0_len
# copy the lower triangular matrix to the upper triangular matrix
df2[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)] = df2.T[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)]
# create a DataFrame from the numpy array with the column names set to score<id>
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = [f"score{i}" for i in range(len(df))])
```

With `df` given as

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[['a','b','c']],
     [['d','b','c']],
     [['a','b','c']],
     [['a','b','c']]],
     columns = ["list_of_value"])
```

the profiling for this code results in a running time of only 1.68ms.

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop
```

### UPDATE

Instead of operating on the entire DataFrame, just picking the Series that is needed gives a huge speedup.

Three methods to iterate over the entries in the Series have been tested, and all of them are more or less equal regarding the performance.

```py
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame([[['a','b','c']], [['d','b','c']], [['a','b','c']], [['a','b','c']]], columns = ["list_of_value"])
# %%timeit df = pd.DataFrame([[random.choices(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), k = 15)] for _ in range(100)], columns = ["list_of_value"])

# create a matrix filled with ones (thus the diagonal is already filled with ones)
df2 = np.ones(shape = (len(df), len(df)))

# get the Series from the DataFrame
dfl = df.list_of_value

for i, d0 in enumerate(dfl.values):
# for i, d0 in dfl.iteritems():  # in terms of performance about equal to the line above
# for i in range(len(dfl)): # slightly less performant than enumerate(dfl.values)
    d0 = set(d0)
    d0_len = len(d0)
    # the inner loop starts at i+1 because we don't need to calculate the diagonal
    for j in range(i + 1, len(dfl)):
        df2[j, i] = len(d0.intersection(dfl.iloc[j])) / d0_len
# copy the lower triangular matrix to the upper triangular matrix
df2[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)] = df2.T[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)]
# create a DataFrame from the numpy array with the column names set to score<id>
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = [f"score{i}" for i in range(len(dfl))])
```

There are a lot of pitfalls with pandas. E.g. always access the rows of a DataFrame or Series via `df.iloc[0]` instead of `df[0]`. Both works but `df.iloc[0]` is much faster.

The timings for the first matrix with 4 elements each with a list of size 3 resulted in a speedup of about 3 times as fast.

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 443 µs per loop
```

And when using a bigger dataset I got far better results with a speedup of over 11:

```
# operating on the DataFrame
10 loop, best of 3: 565 ms per loop

# operating on the Series
10 loops, best of 3: 47.7 ms per loop
```

### UPDATE 2

When not using pandas at all (during the calculation), you get another significant speedup. Therefore you simply need to convert the column to operate on into a list.

```py
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame([[['a','b','c']], [['d','b','c']], [['a','b','c']], [['a','b','c']]], columns = ["list_of_value"])
# %%timeit df = pd.DataFrame([[random.choices(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), k = 15)] for _ in range(100)], columns = ["list_of_value"])

# convert the column of the DataFrame to a list
dfl = list(df.list_of_value)

# create a matrix filled with ones (thus the diagonal is already filled with ones)
df2 = np.ones(shape = (len(dfl), len(dfl)))

for i, d0 in enumerate(dfl):
    d0 = set(d0)
    d0_len = len(d0)
    # the inner loop starts at i+1 because we don't need to calculate the diagonal
    for j in range(i + 1, len(dfl)):
        df2[j, i] = len(d0.intersection(dfl[j])) / d0_len
# copy the lower triangular matrix to the upper triangular matrix
df2[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)] = df2.T[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)]
# create a DataFrame from the numpy array with the column names set to score<id>
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = [f"score{i}" for i in range(len(dfl))])
```

On the data provided in the question we only see a slightly better result compared to the first update.

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 363 µs per loop
```

But when using bigger data (100 rows with lists of size 15) the advantage gets obvious:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 5.26 ms per loop
```

Here a comparison of all the suggested methods:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|          | Using the Dataset from the question     |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| Question | 100 loops, best of 3: 4.63 ms per loop  |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| Answer   | 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 ms per loop |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| Update 1 | 1000 loops, best of 3: 447 µs per loop  |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| Update 2 | 1000 loops, best of 3: 362 µs per loop  |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: In case you don't need a DataFrame you can leave away the conversion from a numpy array to a DataFrame which will save you `0.36 ms` result in a running time of `1.32 ms`. And leaving away the copying of the lower triangular matrix will save you another `0.14 ms` resulting in a total running time of `1.18 ms`.

Comment: FWIW, I would suggest timing this on a larger dataframe than that provided by the OP, to have an idea of real world performance, altho ideally the OP would give some more details about the best way to do that (I just expanded from 4 to 400 rows myself, but that's not the only way to do it, obv)

Comment: I will be running it on 20k rows atleast .. let's see, 'm running the code at the moment.

Comment: Well with numba you also have the option to parallelize the code when running on a multicore CPU. Or if you have access to a Cuda enabled GPU you might want to have a look into cupy

Comment: it is taking roughly 6 hours to run for 11k rows

Comment: can you share some data? Or the specs of how exactly the data should look like? How much time did it take you before?

Comment: it took around 24 hours before, i cant share the data unfortunately..

Comment: I just remembered a small detail which brings you a huge performance boost! instead of operating on the DataFrame just operate on the Series `df.list_of_value.values`! That again resulted in an enormous speedup! I'll update my code with the code and timing results.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is well answered I will show a more readable and also very efficient alternative:

```
from itertools import product
len_df = df.shape[0]
values = tuple(map(lambda comb: np.isin(*comb).sum() / len(comb[0]),
         product(df['list_of_value'], repeat=2)))

pd.DataFrame(index=df['id'],
             columns=df['id'],
             data=np.array(values).reshape(len_df, len_df))
```

---

```
id         0         1         2         3
id                                        
0   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
1   0.666667  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
2   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
3   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

---

```
%%timeit
len_df = df.shape[0]
values = tuple(map(lambda comb: np.isin(*comb).sum() / len(comb[0]),
         product(df['list_of_value'], repeat=2)))

pd.DataFrame(index=df['id'],
             columns=df['id'],
             data=np.array(values).reshape(len_df, len_df))

850 µs ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
#convert the column of the DataFrame to a list
dfl = list(df.list_of_value)

# create a matrix filled with ones (thus the diagonal is already filled with ones)
df2 = np.ones(shape = (len(dfl), len(dfl)))

for i, d0 in enumerate(dfl):
    d0 = set(d0)
    d0_len = len(d0)
    # the inner loop starts at i+1 because we don't need to calculate the diagonal
    for j in range(i + 1, len(dfl)):
        df2[j, i] = len(d0.intersection(dfl[j])) / d0_len
# copy the lower triangular matrix to the upper triangular matrix
df2[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)] = df2.T[np.mask_indices(len(df2), np.triu)]
# create a DataFrame from the numpy array with the column names set to score<id>
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = [f"score{i}" for i in range(len(dfl))])

470 µs ± 79.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not inclined to change your first line, although I'm sure it could be faster, because it's not going to be the bottleneck as your data gets larger.  But the second line could be, and is also extremely easy to improve:

Change this:

```
s.dot(s.T).div(s.sum(1))
```

To:

```
arr=s.values
np.dot( arr, arr.T ) / arr[0].sum()
```

That's just doing it in numpy instead of pandas, but often you'll get a huge speedup.  On your small, sample data it will only speed up by 2x, but if you increase your dataframe from 4 rows to 400 rows, then I see a speedup of over 20x.

As an aside, I would be inclined to not worry about the triangular aspect of the problem, at least as far as speed.  You have to make the code considerably more complex and you probably aren't even gaining any speed in a situation like this.

Conversely, if conserving storage space is important, then obviously retaining only the upper (or lower) triangle will cut your storage needs by slightly more than half.

(If you really do care about the triangular aspect for dimensionality numpy does have related functions/methods but I don't know them offhand and, again, it's not clear to me if it's worth the extra complexity in this case.)